# How to use view children in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a html code like this with template reference variable for `app-image-upload-component`

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images"; let i = index>
  <app-image-upload #imageUpload (click)="uploadImage(i)" (image)="setImageData($event, i)">
    <img src="assets/img/camera-img.png" alt="img">
    <h4>Upload Image</h4>
  </app-image-upload>
</div>
```

Then in my typescript code, i am doing something like this

```
@ViewChild('imageUpload') imageUpload: ImageUploadComponent;

uploadImage(index) {
  console.log('index', index);
  this.imageUpload.showImageBrowseDlg();
}
```

When i fire `click event on app-image-upload`, then it always shows `index value 0`, no matter what is the index of `*ngFor`.

I know this is happening because `#imageUpload` is refrencing only to the first element of `ngFor`, so is there a way to reference all elements of `*ngFor` differently and to use them, as required in my code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html) which has a [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html) of components.

```
import {ViewChildren,QueryList} from '@angular/core';
    @ViewChildren('imageUpload') imageUploads: QueryList<ImageUploadComponent>;

    uploadImage(index) {
      console.log('index', index);
      this.imageUploads.find((imgUpld,i)=>{
          return index == i;
      }).showImageBrowseDlg();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out how to solve this issue, instead of `@ViewChild`, i can use `@ViewChildren` and can do something like this.

```
@ViewChildren(ImageUploadComponent) imageUploadChildren: QueryList<ImageUploadComponent>;

#Subscribe for changes, so that if we delete any children, then it must new array.

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.imageUploadChildrenArray = this.imageUploadChildren.toArray();
  this.imageUploadChildren.changes.subscribe(childern => {
  this.imageUploadChildrenArray = childern.toArray();
});
```

}

```
uploadImage(index) {
  this.imageUploadChildrenArray[index].showImageBrowseDlg();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a #ref to handle function. Make sure that u export your upload directive with exportAs and assign a ref to it. See an example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/BN2dreniteQag82h28BC?p=preview

```
  @Directive({
    selector: '[upload]',
    exportAs: 'upload'
  })
  export class Upload {
    static i =0;
    constructor() {
      this.instanceI = Upload.i++;
      console.log('upload');
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      Last handled upload {{last}}
      <div *ngFor="let i of items">
        <h2 upload #uploadRef="upload" (click)="handle(uploadRef)">Hello {{i}}</h2>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    constructor() {
    }

    handle(uploadRef) {
      console.log(uploadRef);
      this.last = uploadRef.instanceI;
    }
  }
```